# Why is PyScript not compatible with the yfinance library?

Tags: python, yfinance, pyscript

I am adding yfinance to the  tags in index.html, yfinance is installed on my system (globally with pip install in terminal), and I am importing it at the start of my  tags, yet whenever I try to open index.html I get a permanent loading screen.

I have tried importing yfinance into index.html through  rather than  but no luck.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When you say `yfinance` is installed on my system, are you installing them via the `packages` key in py-config? https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/elements/py-config.html